# Can external events cause an open DbConnection to close?

Tags: .net, oledbconnection

My scenario is that I'm creating an `OleDbTransaction` that will later be either committed or rolled back.  Since the corresponding `OleDbConnection` needs to remain open during the lifetime of the transaction, I'm wondering if some external event (e.g. the SQL Server crashes or my network connection goes down) can cause the connection to close?  I know I can listen for `DbConnection.StateChange` events, but if the only code that can change the state of the connection is my own then I don't need to fuss with that.  Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here's some code to add additional context to the question:

```
public class DBAccess {
    private OleDbConnection cn = null;
    private OleDbTransaction tn = null;
    private const string cnString = "my connection string";

    public void UpdateField(string fieldName, object data, int key) {
        if (tn == null) {
            cn = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
            cn.StateChange += Connection_StateChange;
            tn = cn.BeginTransaction();
        }

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE MYTABLE SET " + fieldname + "=" + data.ToString() + "WHERE TABLEKEY=" + key, cn, tn);

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1) {
            throw new ApplicationException();
        }
    }

    public void Commit() {
        if (tn != null) {
            tn.Commit();
            cn.Close();
            tn = null;
        }
    }

    public void Rollback() {
        if (tn != null) {
            tn.Rollback();
            cn.Close();
            tn = null;
        }
    }

    private void Connection_StateChange(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e) {
        // can anything other than my code calling cn.Close() get me here?
}
```

In my application, a user might make several changes to different fields in the table over a period of time...each one would be a separate call to `UpdateField()`.  When they're ready to save their changes, they'd press the save button and code would call my class's `Commit()` method...there will also be a discard changes button that would cause a call to my class's `Rollback()` method.  So, the connection and the transaction would need to stay open over a period of time.  During that time something may happen to the connection to the database that would cause a commit or rollback to fail.  If registering for the `StateChange` event means that I get notified right away that the database is now inaccessible I can do something about it then.  Otherwise I have to handle it at commit/rollback time.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I'm understanding your question correctly.  Typically you open the connection, submit the transaction and then check to see if any rows were affected or not.  If 0 rows came back then you know that no rows were committed and you can try again, or...  Moreover, if you wrap the whole thing in a "try > catch" then you can further catch errors.

If you open a connection then the connection gets closed (for some outside reason) then you try to commit the command, an error will be thrown which you can capture in the catch.

The "try > catch" will catch the errors if they occur and the "int result..." will show you if your changes were committed or not.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like:

```
try 
{
    //....
    int result = myOleDBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (result <= 0) { /*the command executed but, nothing changed on the datasource so you can decide what to do here*/ }
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    //if you get here then a problem has occurred and you can choose how to deal with it.
}
```

Comment: Edited my post to provide additional context.

Comment: So, I'm still not sure about the workflow and why packaging all the object  changes to one commit (or just don't commit if the changes shouldn't be committed to the database) but... Assuming your class has properties and a save method then, why not just grab a copy of the original class and put it off to the side.  Then your users can make changes and keep saving the class that is under work (presumably making update statements?).  If you want to rollback then, just save a copy of the class you have sitting off to the side.

Comment: As a matter of principle I don't like writing code for things that existing code can accomplish, and when I first started this the transaction mechanism appealed to me since it's already there.  That being said, I think the benefit of your simpler approach outweighs the cost of what is turning out to be a mess to code.  Still curious about my original question, but this will work.  Thanks for the suggestion.